# QMainWindow and docks positioning

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow, dockable-windows

I use C++, Qt 4.8.7 for creating GUI application under Windows. I have additional main window as a tab (see an image below). A, B, C, D are dockable widgets. How can I put B widget on the top of C widget? I was able to do it via mouse, but I'd like to do it programmatically. I don't want to have tabified docks.

BTW, do I have to create a dummy zero-sized central widget?  Are dockable widgets more stable in Qt 5.x? Moving docks within my mainwindow is not comfortable (I've created empty small central widget).

[image: QMainWindow with docks]

Comment: I suspect you are using dockable widgets in a pretty improper way.

Comment: Is [dock nesting](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#dockNestingEnabled-prop) what you're looking for?